# Buying a SIM card in Hungary for travel to Slovakia and Austria

Tags: europe, cellphones, hungary, mobile-operators, roaming

I am planning a trip which begins in Hungary, continues in Slovkia (most of the duration) and ends in Austria. Coming from outside the EU, it seems it would be a good idea for me to buy a local SIM card, for making local calls, calls to the subsequent countries I'm visiting, and for being accessible to family members at home in case of an emergency. It is important for me, of course, not pay higher "roaming" costs when making or accepting calls outside of Hungary (where I will first arrive).

What would be my best option for getting such a SIM card - so as to minimize the price and the hassle of getting it? Please also explain where to get the SIM.

Additional information:

- I don't speak Hungarian (I speak English and some French).
- The total duration of the trip is a little over two weeks.
- I use Internet-based messaging applications like WhatsApp, but I don't watch videos or anything else that requires a lot of bandwidth.
- I'm arriving in Budapest by air.

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/internet-telecoms/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm, roaming is consistent across the EU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EU regulations for roaming fees](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/internet-telecoms/mobile-roaming-costs/index_en.htm) make it no longer necessary to get local SIM cards in each country.

Since you're arriving in Hungary I suggest getting your SIM card there. [This guide](https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-hungary/) (from late 2018) has very detailed information on getting SIM cards both at the airport and in the city.

For a start, you can check [Telenor](https://en.telenor.hu/prepaid-recurring-internet) and [Vodafone](https://www.vodafone.hu/english/plans-services/pay-as-you-go-plans) (in English). In theory, all packages should be valid across the EU but I still suggest to double-confirm this and check the fine print.